# Internet Explorer Shows XHTML page without CSS, yet shows CSS on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml

The raw XHTML is just displaying in internet explorer. No CSS is shown at all. I can't seem to pinpoint the issue of this problem. I ran both my XHTML and CSS through the W3C validators and had zero errors checked with XHTML 1.0 Strict and CSS 2.1. 
I suspect the something to do with my DOCTYPE or the `<link>` in my XHTML. Any help is appreciated!

XHTML (DOCTYPE and HEAD):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!-- DOCTYPE is set to STRICT-->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

    <title>Flags</title>


    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Flags.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
</html>
```

Page in:

Internet Explorer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caG1i.png

Chrome:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/h95hF.png

Notes: The CSS is called Flags.css and is located in the same directory as the XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check the developer tools in Internet Explorer. Are you using the correct mime for your CSS? What about headers you've set?

Remove the meta element, it is not only invalid it's completely out of context for XHTML; you *are* setting the mime to `application/xhtml+xml` right?

*Never* use capitol letters for files unless they are intended as an explicit download-only resource; all web resources *must* be lower case as part of your good practices (and use dashes for public facing URLs, never underscores; research correct context of characters on Wikipedia).

Finally you're lacking the `media` attribute with the `screen` value...

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],'application/xhtml+xml'))
{
 header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8');
}
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Flags</title>
<link href="flags.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

My entire site is proper XHTML (1.1 currently, converting to XHTML5 for the next version release) so feel free to look at it linked from my user profile.